# Sorting array by date in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm tryin' to sort an `array` by **date**, but the result seems off. As you can see in the picture below the `0 index` should be in the last.

**Result:**

[image]

**My Code**

```
$next_Data = json_decode('[{"EmployeeID":102,"DateTimeRecord":"7/31/2018 9:39:13 PM","InOut":"0"},
                        {"EmployeeID":102,"DateTimeRecord":"7/31/2018 9:39:13 PM","InOut":"0"},
                        {"EmployeeID":102,"DateTimeRecord":"7/31/2018 9:39:13 PM","InOut":"0"},
                        {"EmployeeID":102,"DateTimeRecord":"8/1/2018 6:43:04 AM","InOut":"1"},
                        {"EmployeeID":102,"DateTimeRecord":"8/1/2018 6:43:05 AM","InOut":"1"},
                        {"EmployeeID":102,"DateTimeRecord":"8/1/2018 6:43:06 AM","InOut":"1"},
                        {"EmployeeID":102,"DateTimeRecord":"8/1/2018 6:13:25 PM","InOut":"0"},
                        {"EmployeeID":102,"DateTimeRecord":"8/1/2018 6:13:25 PM","InOut":"0"},
                        {"EmployeeID":102,"DateTimeRecord":"8/2/2018 20:13:25 PM","InOut":"1"},
                        {"EmployeeID":102,"DateTimeRecord":"8/1/2018 6:13:25 PM","InOut":"0"},
                        {"EmployeeID":102,"DateTimeRecord":"8/2/2018 6:54:12 AM","InOut":"1"},
                        {"EmployeeID":102,"DateTimeRecord":"8/2/2018 6:54:12 AM","InOut":"1"},
                        {"EmployeeID":102,"DateTimeRecord":"8/2/2018 6:54:12 AM","InOut":"1"},
                        {"EmployeeID":102,"DateTimeRecord":"8/2/2018 12:13:25 PM","InOut":"0"}]');


$next_Data = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $next_Data)));

        foreach ($next_Data as $key => $part) 
        {
            $sort[$key] = strtotime($part->DateTimeRecord);
        }

array_multisort($sort, SORT_ASC, $next_Data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtotime()` returns FALSE for this value, so it is sorted as a 0, and thus appears first. `20:13 PM` is not a valid time; it should be either `8:13 PM` or `20:13`.

Comment: Oh my god. Thanks for this.